# how to set password for zip file with out path in OSX

Tags: macos

I have file example.ipa, I need make it zip and set password for that zip folder.

I tried this command in My terminal :

```
 zip-er /users/someName/NewFolder /users/someName/example.ipa
```

It's working fine.but when i make it unzip the file.

it showing `user --> someName --> Desktop --> example.ipa`

can please any one help me how it will show with out showing path how can i make zip file and set password this zip folder

Thanks advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would tend to use `7-zip` for this - it is easily installed, either with `homebrew` or without. The trick is to change directory to where your files are before creating the zip file, like this:

```
cd /Users/FreddyFrog/Desktop && 7z a ~/zipfile.7z * -pSECRET -mhe
```

So that will change directory to `FreddyFrog's` Desktop and then create an archive called `zipfile.7z` in **your** home directory of all FreddyFrog's Desktop files and encrypt it with the password `SECRET` and also encrypt the names of the files in the archive (`-mhe`).

Extract with

```
7z x ~/zipfile.7z
```

Further examples [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/7-zip-examples).